# Building m4 from source on FreeBSD error: don't know how to make ../../build-aux/snippet/c++defs.h

Tags: compiling, make, m4

I'm using FreeBSD 13.0-CURRENT (for more information see [here](http://mpuw-um9c5.byethost4.com/unamea.txt)), and I want to use [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html). Downloaded [this version](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/m4/m4-latest.tar.xz) of it, configured, and tried to make. But it gives error as stated in the title: error: `don't know how to make ../../build-aux/snippet/c++defs.h`. For the whole log, [see here](http://mpuw-um9c5.byethost4.com/m4make.log). Any idea? Thanks to all suggestions and answers.

EDIT1: indeed, my m4 version is 1.4.17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unpacked m4-1.4.17 here (Fedora 31; your `latest` might be another version... but it seems to date from 2013). The offending file is there (in `build-aux/snippet`). There is a script called `bootstrap`included, but that presumably is only needed for sources straight from version control.

The traditional `./configure; make` dance goes fine, but fails after compiling a bunch of stuff with:

```
freadahead.c: In function 'freadahead':
freadahead.c:91:3: error: #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
```

A simple search for "GNU m4 FreeBSD" leads to [FreshPorts](https://www.freshports.org/devel/m4), FreeBSD's [m4 manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=m4&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) talks about a `-g` option to activate GNU m4 compatitility. Why aren't those enough? Presumably whatever patched version FreshPorts carries is a better starting point (if they are civilized and carry original sources and separate patches, porting the patches to another version is less work than debugging this mess yourself).

Comment: +1.  Indeed, `pkg search m4` yields amongst others: `m4-1.4.18_1,1    GNU M4`.  I suspect `pkg install m4` might well solve the OP's needs.

Comment: Thank you for your early reply. I’ll try that out. If my pkg tool didn’t have any problems, I would not mess around with the source though.

Comment: @Chrimpyslime, ask about your pkg tool problems then...

Comment: Already asked about, no reply from them since 10 days before. [See here](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=244221). Maybe I have to set dome flag to let them know they have to reply?

Comment: Thanks! While installing from pkg is not available, installing from ports succeed.